# jQuery Typeahead return 404 (Not Found) in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, ajax, api, laravel-5.4, typeahead

I add to routes/api.php

```
Route::get('v1/crosses.json', 'API\BasicController@crosses')
```

My front.js include

```
require('jquery-typeahead');
$.typeahead({
  input: '#search',
  source: {
    cross: {
      ajax: {
        type: "GET",
        url: 'api/v1/crosses.json',
        path: "data.crosses",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          term: "11"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Laravel 5.4 - controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class BasicController extends Controller
{
  public function crosses(Request $request): JsonResponse
  {
   return response()->json([
        "status" => true,
        "error" => null,
        "data" => [
            "crosses" => [
               'sample'       
             ]
        ]
    ]);
  }
}
```

When I start writing in the #search field, I immediately begin to fly queries. Only they do not reach the goal. The console issues a 404 error. I thought something might be wrong with routing but in `route:list` it shows this request and it can also be opened in the browser. Only when referring through ajax crashes 'not found'

Comment: if url: 'api/v1/crosses.json' so in the route `Route::get('api/v1/crosses.json', 'API\BasicController@crosses')`

Comment: i use routes/api.php -> GET|HEAD | api/v1/crosses.json   |   | App\Http\Controllers\API\BasicController@crosses | api  |

Comment: did you already require your api route? or try in main routes.php dont custom file route.

Comment: I transfer in `web.php`, I add a prefix `/api`, the error similar

Comment: add your route definition in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using nginx. Response is very big. Need increase size of buffers

```
fastcgi_buffers 16 256k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
```